# Vector space and "linear structure"

Tags: vector-spaces

This question really only concerns terminology. In the linear algebra lectures that I am watching, the professor refers to the "linear structure" of a vector space. I know the definition of linearity in the context of a linear transformation, but that's a map between vector spaces. The vector spaces themselves do not seem to have "linear structure." I cannot figure out what exactly this term means. I believe another name for vector space is a "linear space," and that this must be related, but I cannot figure out what this could be referring to unless the ability to take linear combinations is the goal.

Comment: "Linear structure" in this context usually just refers to the addition and scalar multiplication of the vector space. So yes, they are referring to the ability to take linear combinations.

Comment: So, to be clear, "linear structure" essentially means closed under linear combinations?

Comment: I would not say that. Saying that a set is "closed under" linear combinations presupposes that we have an addition and scalar multiplication (i.e. a linear structure) with which those linear combinations would be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, a vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ is endowed with two different "structures", one is given by addition, $+$, and gives the set $V$ a structure of abelian group $(V, +)$, the other one is given by multiplication of vectors in $V$ by elements in $F$, called scalars, and satisfies some axioms. The result is that the set $V$ of vectors must be closed with respect to both addition and scalar multiplication. That is, if $v$ and $v'$ are vectors in $V$, then also the sum $v+v'$ must be a vector in $V$ and if $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$ is a scalar, then $\lambda v$ must be a vector in $V$. You may summarize these closure properties by saying that $V$ is closed under linear combinations of vectors, that is $\lambda v+\lambda'v'$ is in $V$ for all $\lambda,\lambda'\in\mathbb{F}$ and $v,v'\in V$. Vectors of the form $\lambda v+\lambda'v'$ are called linear combinations of $v$ and $v'$. This can be a reason for calling a vector space a linear space, because it is closed under linear combinations of vectors. Linear combinations appear everywhere in vector spaces: if you fix a basis for the space, then every vector can be written (uniquely) as a linear combination of vectors in the basis.